# Unrealistic Tx-Power for wifi interface

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, wifi-configuration

I recently built a desktop computer with the following parts:

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X CPU
- ASRock AM4/X570M Pro4 mother board
- Intel AX210 wifi/bluetooth card. It's mounted on a M2 slot

I'm on Archlinux. Everything works well but the network card. The card is recognized, but neither the wifi nor the bluetooth work.

When I run iwconfig on the wifi interface, I get a weird value:

```
❯ iwconfig wlp4s0
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I've been trying various kernels/firmwares with no change all day and I'm starting to think the card faulty.
Is it normal to have this kind of value for tx-Power?

Comment: Have you actually connected an antenna to the M.2 Wifi network card? From https://www.amazon.co.uk/3000Mbps-Bluetooth-Antennas-Wireless-AX210NGW/dp/B08YNG9PQM it looks like you would expect to connect antennae to one of the u.fl connectors marked "2" and "1". If you don't do that then the card may well refuse to enable it's power amplifier and so return an insanely low power output, as the reflected power could easily damage the output stage.

Comment: No, I don't have antennae, I bought the card without it. Are they *absolutely* necessary? Note that the BT also doesn't work, and that's the part I'm more interested in. And yes, I do have a M.2 slot labeled "wifi" on the mobo, that's where the card is plugged.

Comment: Yes they are necessary. You may have bought a version of the card intended for a laptop where the antennae may have been expected to be present already.

Comment: You should probably get something like these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/BOOBRIE-Omnidirectional-Signal-Antenna-Pigtail/dp/B08JLG2SNY/ref=sr_1_3?crid=3F36VW44T96GF&keywords=wifi+u.fl&qid=1665264552&s=electronics&sprefix=wifi+u.fl%2Celectronics%2C83&sr=1-3

Comment: Got it. Please turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: I've added an answer, but I don't mind if you want to wait to actually get antennae before accepting just so you can be sure it is the solution.

Comment: Ok! They should be here in on Monday.

Comment: Yeah it was the antenna. I just installed it and wifi and bluetooth work. The Tx-Power value is still weird, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to make sure about is that you have connected an antenna to the M.2 Wifi network card.

From [amazon.co.uk/3000Mbps-Bluetooth-Antennas-Wireless-AX210NGW/dp/…](https://www.amazon.co.uk/3000Mbps-Bluetooth-Antennas-Wireless-AX210NGW/dp/B08YNG9PQM) you can see that you should connect antennae to one or both of the u.fl connectors marked "2" and "1".

[image: Wifi Card]

If you don't connect at least one antenna to the "MAIN" port then the card may well refuse to enable it's power amplifier and I could see it returning an insanely low power output, as the reflected power could easily damage the output stage.

If you need antennae then you can easily purchase sets by searching for terms like ["wifi u.fl"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=wifi+u.fl) on sites like Amazon which will get you an antenna connector set that can go from the internal u.fl connector to the antenna which is typically an SMA connection:

[image]

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XNBN7TT)